# Make a QuickGrid column un-filterable?

Tags: filter, blazor, quickgrid

I'm using a Blazor QuickGrid.  I could be wrong about this, but I have noticed that, at least by default, *every* QuickGrid column seems to automatically offer a 'filtering' capability.  My question is this: What if I want to prevent a particular column from being 'filterable' (if that's the word)?  Is there a way to do that?

For what it's worth, a few rather compromised options have occurred to me...

- On the column I'm talking about, I suppose I could have the 'filter drop down box' (or whatever it's called) simply appear as is normal, but have it display some sort of text like "No Filter Available".
- As another idea, is there a way to at least hide the filter icon dedicated to a particular column?  I know an invisible icon might not prevent the User from clicking in that general area anyway, but no visible icon *might* serve as a visual clue to the User that that particular column was not set up for filtering.

Comment: By default columns are neither filterable nor sortable.

Comment: please add some relevant code. Did you use the scaffolding command of the visual studio preview, or how did you create the quickgrid?

Comment: You have have helped me see my mistake.  Fwiw, I was using 'ColumnOption' on the Column I was asking about.  Although there appears to be no specific attribute in the ColumnOption that refers to Filtering (unless I'm missing it), I didn't realize that just by virtue of adding a ColumnOption, that alone would make a QuickGrid column filterable.  With your help, once I took out that particular ColumnOption, the column was still thankfully Sort-able, but was no longer Filterable.